# получить список годов с числом записей в этом году

Tags: mysql

Нужно получить список годов и относящихся к ним записей для архива.
Вот, мой пример, не знаю как сделать выборку count(записи) для каждого года

```
select year(time) as year, count(*) as count from entries group by time
```

Comment: group by year, видимо, подразумевался?

Comment: имя столбца time, нужно получить все года и кол-во записей в каждом

Comment: Ну так это ваш запрос и есть, только группировать надо по году, который вы уже получили в селекте и дали алиас year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select year(time) as year, count(*) as count 
  from entries 
 group by year(time)
```

Наверное еще можно так:

```
select date_format(time, '%Y') as year, count(*) as count 
  from entries 
 group by date_format(time, '%Y')
```